# SQL Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

This query works in Oracle:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "DATE_OF_PUBLICATION") AS years,  
       Count("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS events,   
       Max("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS max_losses, 
       Sum("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS sum_losses 
FROM (
  select * 
  from (
     select "DATE_OF_PUBLICATION",
            "LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)" 
     FROM TEST 
     ORDER BY "LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)" DESC 
  )
) 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "DATE_OF_PUBLICATION") 
ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "DATE_OF_PUBLICATION")
```

Now, I executed this query in SQLServer:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,"DATE_OF_PUBLICATION") AS years, 
       Count("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS events,   
       Max("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS max_losses, 
       sum("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS sum_losses 
FROM (
  select * 
  from (
    select "DATE_OF_PUBLICATION",
           "LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)" 
    FROM TEST 
    ORDER BY "LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)" DESC 
  )
) 
GROUP BY DATEPART (YEAR ,"DATE_OF_PUBLICATION") 
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR ,"DATE_OF_PUBLICATION")
```

I get this error:

```
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and 
common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error crystal-clearly states, `ORDER BY` is invalid in subqueries.

Also: in SQL server, when you use a subquery, it must have a name:

```
select * from ( select .....)
```

is invalid, whereas

```
select * from ( select .....) as tablename
```

is valid

Also, you have two needless subquery levels.
The following should work:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(YEAR , "DATE_OF_PUBLICATION") AS years, 
    Count("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS events, 
    Max("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS max_losses, 
    Sum("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS sum_losses 
FROM AAA_20180711
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR , "DATE_OF_PUBLICATION") 
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR, "DATE_OF_PUBLICATION")
```

Comment: SELECT DATEPART(YEAR , "DATE_OF_PUBLICATION") AS years, Count("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS events, Max("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS max_losses, 
Sum("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS sum_losses FROM (select * from(select "DATE_OF_PUBLICATION","LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)" FROM Test)) 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR , "DATE_OF_PUBLICATION") ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR, "DATE_OF_PUBLICATION")

Comment: Updated answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks so much, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep the order by, if you use

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM ...
```

in your subquery.

However, the "error" is pointing out that in general, subqueries should not need ORDER BY clauses.   Consider why you feel you need the ORDER BY, you probably can safely remove it

Answer (score 0):

The inner `order by` is not needed at all. While Oracle tolerates it (and probably simply ignores it), SQL Server doesn't like it (and rightfully so). You can remove it completely from the query. The only one that is needed is the outer `order by`. Additionally: the nested derived table is also not needed.

You can simplify the query to:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,"DATE_OF_PUBLICATION") AS years, 
       Count("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS events,   
       Max("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS max_losses, 
       sum("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS sum_losses 
FROM TEST 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR ,"DATE_OF_PUBLICATION") 
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR ,"DATE_OF_PUBLICATION")
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Order by` clause and don't forget to add an `alias` to nested query,

use the next query after modification:-

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,"DATE_OF_PUBLICATION") AS years, 
       Count("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS events,   
       Max("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS max_losses, 
       sum("LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)") AS sum_losses 
FROM (
  select * 
  from (
    select "DATE_OF_PUBLICATION",
           "LOSS_AMOUNT_(LOCAL_CCY)" 
    FROM TEST 
  )t1
) t2 
GROUP BY DATEPART (YEAR ,"DATE_OF_PUBLICATION") 
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR ,"DATE_OF_PUBLICATION")
```